# A-Frame: Error when using tracked-controls-webxr

Tags: html, aframe, virtual-reality, webxr, entity-component-system

I am using the A-Frame watcher plugin to create the scene, I was creating two entities for left and right `tracked-controls-webxr`. When I start my dev server from webpack I get this error:

```
core:a-node:error Failure loading node:   TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'buttonStates')
    at init (tracked-controls-webxr.js:25:64)
    at initComponent (component.js:320:10)
    at i.updateProperties (component.js:302:12)
    at i.module.exports.Component (component.js:78:8)
    at new i (component.js:662:15)
    at HTMLElement.value (a-entity.js:332:19)
    at HTMLElement.value (a-entity.js:495:12)
    at HTMLElement.value (a-entity.js:463:14)
    at a-entity.js:249:14
    at a-node.js:127:21
```

Originally I had the two entities as childs to the camera cause that makes sense to me, but the page wouldn't load, I moved them out the page loads but I still get the errors.

Answer (score 0):

[afaik](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/tracked-controls.html) the `tracked-controls` are supposed to set up the`tracked-controls-webxr`:

> tracked-controls sets two components that handles different Web API versions for VR:
>
> - tracked-controls-webvr
> - tracked-controls-webxr

You're getting an error, because [`tracked-controls-webxr` are trying to access `tracked-controls`](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/tracked-controls-webxr.js#L26) and fail - hence `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'buttonStates')`.

---

Try using `tracked-controls`, or mimic [their setup](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/tracked-controls.js#L33-L39)